# Given a hostname how can one identify the right scheme for it?

Tags: python, url, curl

Given a `hostname` by a user how can one compose a `URL` with the right `scheme`?

And even more, how can you identify if `www` should be prepended?

e.g: `ryanair.com`

```
https://ryanair.com     -> 504 Timeout
https://www.ryanair.com -> 200 OK
http://ryanair.com      -> https://www.ryanair.com
https://ryanair.com     -> https://www.ryanair.com
```

Right answer for `ryanair.com` should be `https://www.ryanair.com`.

Has anyone confronted with this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply request the URL with a plain HTTP request and see where you get redirected to. Not all sites offer HTTPS, but virtually all will offer HTTP (if HTTP happens to fail you might want to retry with HTTPS, but that's going to be exceedingly rare). You cannot assume that a `www.` subdomain exists, that's an entirely arbitrary, legacy convention with no inherent technical meaning.

Comment: These days you might want to try HTTPS first and then fall back to HTTP if that fails.

Comment: Some sites have a parking page which is a good fine site, just not with the content you expect (perhaps the Apache welcome page, or perhaps their hosting provider's default page). Some sites have a parking page on the main site and their actual content on www.example.com (or www1, or publicweb, or site, or ...)

Comment: @tripleee This is what I am doing now (HTTPS first), but as you can see you get a timeout with ryanair.

Comment: Timeouts are precisely what you should expect when probing things which might not be there.

Comment: Most sites will offer a plain HTTP version, even if that just redirects to the main HTTPS version, because that's what a browser will do when you type the domain into the address bar. If that's a "parked page", well, none of your business, you aren't a soothsayer to magically guess the right page.

Comment: What do you think about using for example the Google/Bing API and do a search for `ryanair.com` and see what `scheme` ad/or `www` subdomain appears for the first results?

Comment: @alexm92 That's not terribly reliable, as it depends on the company's SEO strength. You should assume/require that the user gives you a valid URL which will lead to the right website if you type it into a browser's address bar; you just need to follow the HTTP request to that URL. If that assumption doesn't hold, it's entirely up in the air what that URL is supposed to refer to.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you can't know without making HTTP requests to see what redirects they do, until you hit an HTTP 200.

Whether you should try http:// or https:// first, that depends on what you're trying to do. If crawling the website, the former, if you intend to use those links in public facing web services, then the later.

So I'd do it like this:

1. request for the naked domain (no www) with https://
2. if that fails or times out then request the naked domain with http://
3. if that fails repeat the above steps, but for www

N.B. most websites that use www will redirect from the naked domain. HTTPS-only websites will redirect from http:// to https:// too. So the safest request you can make is no-www + http://, but I'd start with assuming https, since encrypting the web is now the general trend.